# Chrome developer emulate touch is inaccurate

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, touch-event

Is it just me, or are the emulated touch events built into the Chrome dev tools really wonky? When I emulate touch events and view a site in any of the given device configurations, the touch events are way off the target. For example, I click a button, and my cursor will move to focus on a input field a hundred or so pixels from the top of where I clicked. It's really frustrating.

Has anyone else experienced this? My version of chrome:
**Google Chrome    38.0.2125.101 (Official Build 290379) m**

Answer (score 0):

I tried touch events on a few other sites and it seems to work fine. So it must be something to do with the site I'm working on.